# Power transformer winding labels

Tags: transformer

I have a transformer I can't identify ('SE9D') but the windings are clearly labelled.

The primary is 0 100 117-0 100 117 taps with the 117-0 series link already installed, so that's obviously the 230/240V supply.

There is a 6.3V/0.6A pair, perhaps for heaters because it might have come from a CRO. That's not a problem.

Then there are two pairs, 160V and 500V.  One is marked "DC 50MA" and the other "DC 2MA". There is also one set of three taps labelled 0, 25V and 25V with the additional marking "DC +30MA -65MA".

Question 1: What is the meaning of "DC" in this context?   Is there any way that it is a reference to a characteristic of the transformer?  My assumption is that it simply refers to the usage of these taps in the intended application.
Question 2: Does the MA rating refer to the AC rating of the transformer winding or is it also just a reference to the particular DC circuit that the tap is designed for?

Comment: MA = megaamperes; mA = milliamperes

Comment: It may help if you add a photo of the markings.

Comment: Why?  So you can see that I have transcribed "DC" and "MA" correctly?  That would be a waste of forum resources.

Answer (score 0):

These are only guesses, but I think you have mostly correctly identified the windings. I am assuming it did come from a CRO.
It is very unlikely that you would be deliberately passing a DC current through any of the windings of a mains transformer. Therefore the current ratings are almost certainly those of the DC outputs after their respective rectification.
117-100-0-100-117 is the primary, and without inspecting it, I would think it could be wired either as 234 V or 200V with the windings in series or as 117V or 100V with the pairs in parallel (to match the local mains supply as close as possible).
Yes, 6.3V would be for valve heaters.
Probably the 160V is for the general purpose electronics (valves) HT supply and the 500V possibly for the CRT's high voltage requirement.
The other windings 25-0-25 are most likely for some specialised circuitry, or a negative bias supply, or the device might have been a hybrid design and they were for the semiconductor parts of the design.

Comment: Thank you for the response but I know what the windings are.  The question related to the "DC" and "MA" notations attached to the windings, not to the voltages or how the transformer might be configured for different uses.

Answer (score 0):

It could indeed be for an oscilloscope.

Without photos, there's practically no hope of recognizing which (and even then..!), but consider this power supply schematic from the Heathkit IO-103 for example:

[image]

Source: Heathkit Assembly Manual, 5-Inch Triggered Sweep Oscilloscope, Model IO-103, ©1971 Heath Company; downloaded from: https://frank.pocnet.net/other/sos/Heathkit_IO-103_Oscilloscope.pdf, page 152

The similarity in voltage range and current consumption should be pretty apparent; the low-voltage (±5, 9V) supplies are zener shunt regulated elsewhere, so the resistor values shown here give some idea of current capacity on the 36V winding.

Transformers intended for rectification are often rated in terms of DC output current, usually in a capacitor-input rectifier circuit.  This rectifier gives a fairly low power factor (often PF = 0.5-0.6 at full load), so while it yields more DC voltage than AC RMS input (it's a peak detector circuit, sine peak is \$\sqrt{2}\$ times RMS), this comes at the expense of a stronger-than-corresponding reduction in current capacity; the winding would at least have to see \$\sqrt{2}\$ times more RMS current for energy balance purposes, but it's closer to double instead (more directly: \$I_\text{rms} = \frac{I_\text{DC}}{PF}\$).  Thus it's important to distinguish AC and DC ratings.  Most transformers don't specify, and AC should be assumed.

Older transformers and other components were often marked in all-caps, thus you don't have megaamps, but milliamps most likely.  For another example, contemporary capacitors were often "20MF" or "MFD", and so on.  Perhaps they lacked lowercase, or extended characters like µ, in the stamps or typeface used to label them, but in any case, manufacturers can label components however they wish, as long as a datasheet or custom drawing describes what they are.  You seem to be lucky to have a descriptive label on your transformer!

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response.  "Transformers intended for rectification are often rated in terms of DC output current, usually in a capacitor-input rectifier circuit. " is something I didn't know and explains the marking exactly.  I will assume that the rating applies to a capacitor-input rectifier, and make the necessary adjustments if I use something different.   It hadn't occurred to me the MA might mean megaamps!